# Как сделать методы общими для 2 классов

Tags: java, generics

Здравствуйте . Помогите решить проблему. Есть четыре класса -

```
public class SimpleArray<T> implements Iterable<T> {

   private Object[] array;
   private int position = 0;
   private int i = 0;

    public SimpleArray(int size) {
        this.array = new Object[size];
    }

    public void add(T model) {

      array[position] = model;
      position++;
    }

    public void set(int index, T model) {
        if (index < array.length) {
            array[index] = model;
        }
    }

    public boolean delete(int index) {
        boolean temp = false;
        if (index < array.length) {
            array[index] = null;
            temp = true;
        }
        return temp;
    }

   public T get(int index) {
       return (T) array[index];
   }


    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {

        return new Iterator<T>() {

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                boolean temp = false;
                if (array[i] != null) {
                    temp = true;
                }
                return temp;
            }

            @Override
            public T next() {
                if (array[i] == null) {
                    throw new NoSuchElementException();
                }
                return (T) array[i++];
            }
        };
    }
}


public class RoleStore  extends  AbstractStore  {

    SimpleArray<Role> roles = new SimpleArray<>(100);

    public RoleStore(SimpleArray<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
}


public class UserStore  extends  AbstractStore   {


  SimpleArray<User> user = new SimpleArray<>(100);

    public UserStore(SimpleArray<User> user) {
        this.user = user;
    }


}

public abstract class AbstractStore<T>  {


   private int index = 0;
   private int count = 0;
   private int index2 =0;
   private int count2 = 0;
   private int index3 = 0;
   private int count3 = 0;




    public void add(T model) {
        simpleArray.add(model);
    }


    public boolean replace(String id, T model) {
        boolean result = false;
        while (count < 100 && !result) {
            T temp = simpleArray.get(index);
            Base temp2 = (Base) temp;
            if (temp2.getId() == id) {
                simpleArray.set(index, model);
                result = true;
            }
            index++;
            count++;
        }
        return result;
    }


    public boolean delete(String id) {
        boolean result = false;
        while (count2 < 100 && !result) {
            T temp = simpleArray.get(index2);
            Base tmp = (Base) temp;
            if (tmp.getId() == id) {
                simpleArray.delete(index2);
                result = true;
            }
            index2++;
            count2++;
        }
        return result;
    }


    public T findById(String id) {
        T result = null;
        boolean rsl = false;
        while (count3 < 100 && !rsl) {
            T temp = simpleArray.get(index3);
            Base tmp = (Base) temp;
            if (tmp.getId() == id) {
               result = temp;
              rsl = true;
            }
            index3++;
            count3++;
        }
        return result;
    }
}

public class Role extends Base  {

    protected Role(String id) {
        super(id);
    }
}

public class User extends Base {

    protected User(String id) {
        super(id);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Jerry";
    }
}

public interface Store<T extends Base> {

    void add(T model);

    boolean replace(String id, T model);

    boolean delete(String id);

    T findById(String id);
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы методы из класса `AbstractStore` я мог бы использовать при создании объекта `Role` и `User`. В основе класса `RoleStore` и `UserStore` лежит класс контейнер `SipleArray`.

Comment: Использовать где и как?

Comment: Может попробовать модификатор static?
И разберись с наследованием в своей программе, по моему ты немного переборщил.
Удачи! И да прибудет с тобой Тёмный Лорд!